# Deep Comparison (Eloquent Javascript Chapter 4): code fails a test case

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript from the Eloquent Javascript book. I'm little stumped on how my code fails for the Deep Comparison exercise in Chapter 4 (introduction to objects)

**Goal**

> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true
>   only if they are the same value or are objects with the same
>   properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive
>   call to deepEqual.
>
> To find out whether to compare two things by identity (use the ===
>   operator for that) or by looking at their properties, you can use the
>   typeof operator. If it produces "object" for both values, you should
>   do a deep comparison.

**My code**

```
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2)
{
    var truefalse = undefined;
    var type1 = typeof obj1;
    var type2 = typeof obj2;

// In case both are objects
    if(type1 == 'object' && type2 == 'object')
    {
        var prop1 = [];
        var prop2 = [];
        for(var prop in obj1)
            prop1.push(prop);
        for(var prop in obj2)
            prop2.push(prop); 

        // Test if both objects have the same number of properties
        if(prop1.length == prop2.length)
        {

            // Test if all properties between them have the same names,
            // by generating index for each property in prop1 against prop2
            var indexArray = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < prop1.length; i++)
            {
                var index = prop2.indexOf(prop1[i]);
                indexArray.push(index);
            };

            // If there's no "-1" anywhere in the indices generated
            // (all properties are named the same between them),
            // move on to value comparison for each property
            if(indexArray.indexOf(-1) == -1)
                {
                for(var event in obj1)
                    {
                        if(deepEqual(obj1[event], obj2[event]))
                            truefalse = true
                        else
                            truefalse = false;
                    };
                }

            // Different property names
            else
                truefalse = false;
        }

        // Different number of properties
        else
            truefalse = false;
    }

    // Either/both are not objects
    else
        truefalse = (obj1 === obj2);

    return truefalse;
}

console.log(deepEqual({here: 3, object: 1}, {object: 1, here: 2}))
// → true
```

**My question**

Through some debugging, I suspect that when comparing the values of my `here` property first (3 and 2), it returns false to my `truefalse` variable because they are different from each other. However, when the `for(var event in obj1) {...}` loop moves on to my `object` property, my `truefalse` variable is rewritten as true, as both have the same value.

If this is the correct diagnosis, is there anyway to correct this error? Perhaps I should use an `or` conditional, but I just can't think of a way to combine it with the for loop.

Thank you for all the help you can give to this beginner.

PS. While writing this post, I realized I could have used the `in` test to check if all properties in both objects are named the same, but I'm too tired right now to edit the post. I apologize if that part of my code looks clumsy.

Comment: Your issue is that you are overwriting the value of your `truefalse` variable at each iteration of your `for(var event in obj1)` for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should asume that the function returns true (equals) and when any differences found, returns false right away.

Firtly, change default value of truefalse.

```
var truefalse = true
```

Then, replace

```
for(var event in obj1)
{
    if(deepEqual(obj1[event], obj2[event]))
        truefalse = true
    else
        truefalse = false;
};
```

with

```
for(var event in obj1)
{
    if(deepEqual(obj1[event], obj2[event]) == false)
        return false
};
```

Now it should work!

Rgrds,

Comment: That was indeed very illuminating to me as a beginner. At first I was afraid that would have the same problem, where a true match would reverse the false result and I would end up with a false 'true' result. However, I now realize that in that case, it would not even enter the 'if' clause in the first place, and the false return remains. Thanks again!